# Anyone who can se why my PHP mail script doesnt work

Tags: php

anyone who know why this mail script down´t work ??
please ??
I tried everything but I don't get any mails ..

The HTML Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="generic.css">
</head>
<body>


<div id="header">
<img src="fest800x500.gif" height="500" width="800">
<form action="mail.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
<textarea name="message" width="400"   height="80">meddelande</textarea>
<input type="image" src="skicka.jpg" alt="Submit" width="200" height="80" value="Send">
</form>        


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP script:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$to = 'name@mail.se';
$subject = 'meddelande';
$message = $_POST['message'];
$headers = 'From: name@mail.se' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: name@mail.se' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

}
?>
```

Comment: can you try this on **localhost** ???

Comment: where is your email account settings? But please before you show it here, remove all the credentials

Comment: your script is failing because of 2 things (possibly 3). Enable error reporting and you'll see.

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or logs? Try putting the `mail` function in a conditional statement and report if there's a problem or if it sends correctly (in which case it might be your mail provider blocking the mail as junk).

Comment: You might wanna change this part to

`<input type="image" name="submit" src="skicka.jpg" alt="Submit" width="200" height="80" value="Send">`

Answer (score 0):

You are posting form with image, not with submit button.

And `name='submit'` to your image.

So, you need to check x and y of image.

Therefore, you are not reaching the code withing `if`

Change

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_x'])){
```

Also, for sending mail from local server, you need to configure your SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change input type:

```
<input type="submit" alt="Submit" width="200" height="80" value="Send">
```

Also, if you want give any icon/image to button than you can create a class in css and apply that class in your button.
Like :

```
<input class="your-button-class" type="submit" alt="Submit" width="200" height="80" value="Send">
```